# ImportError: cannot import name 'create_engine' from 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, importação, sqlalchemy

quero usar a biblioteca `SQLalchemy` para python. Até consigo importar ela inteira, porém ocorre um erro de importação ao obter `create_engine`.
Estou usando o `python versão 3.9` e o `sqlalchemy na versão 1.4.23`

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_engine' from 'sqlalchemy' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Por acaso o nome do seu arquivo é `sqlalchemy.py`?

Comment: não, o meu arquivo esta como `app.py`

Comment: Você está utilizando venv? Como fez a instalação da biblioteca? Ao importá-la por completa, o que aparece ao fazer `print(sqlalchemy)`?

Comment: 1º criei um venv e instalei a lib utilizando `pip install sqlalchemy`, e quando faço `print(sqlalchemy)` aparece `<module 'sqlalchemy' (namespace)>`

Comment: O site do SQLAlchemy, assim como o pypi, dizem para instalar assim: `pip install SQLAlchemy`. Foi assim que você fez?